# Visual Foxpro 9 - Home Dir Not Found

Tags: windows-10, foxpro

I am building the visual foxpro 9 on my windows 10 machine. While building the solution, I am getting the 12. HomeDir not found (Exception code c0000005. OLE object may be corrupt)

Any additional configuration or Service packs needs to be installed for Windows 10

Comment: When you say _"I am getting the 12"_. do you mean the `foxpro` error number? `c0000005` on the other hand is not a foxpro error but an internal `C(++)` exception.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to build your project?

Comment: @StefanWuebbe: we are using visual foxpro interop dll to build the exe from our .net windows application. While uploading the homedir path through vfp command in .net application we got the above error

Comment: Yes. We got 12 home dir error not found message from foxpro command

Comment: That sounds as if there is something going wrong in that "interop" dll code/"foxpro command" you mentioned. Can you add the related internal code pieces to your question? See also https://www.vfphelp.com/help/_5wn12pkco.htm

Comment: C0000005 errors in the VFP development environment are often caused by corrupt FOXUSER files. Use SYS(2005) to locate the file, then delete the DBF and FPT file while VFP9 is not running.

Comment: Hi Christof, Can you please let me know where to find SYS(2005) folder in my windows 10 machine